# Can varied temperature while sleeping help quality of sleep?

Tags: human-biology, sleep, temperature

I read [an interesting article](http://www.wsj.com/articles/the-best-temperature-for-a-good-nights-sleep-1456166563) which is about relations between body temperature and quality of sleep.
I'm interested in the phrase from the article.

> Other experiments that varied the ambient temperature—decreasing it early in the night and increasing it in the morning—have shown similar benefits for improving and maintaining sleep.

So I tried to find papers and experiments but it seems my searching ability is pretty poor. I can't find it. Is there someone knows the latest knowledge or papers about this?

plus) In the article, why increasing skin temperature by 0.4 Celsius make core temperature low?